# Android - sqlite inserting error

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm facing this problem while inserting rows to sqlite :

```
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205): Error inserting content=null position=9 id=158823 title=Hà Đông thu gần 160 tỷ đồng từ đấu giá quyền sử dụng đất trong đợt 2 source=Thời báo Ngân hàng - 54 phút trước nextpage=2 page=44 publishedDate=2014-06-29 10:09:04 catid=0 thumb=http://images3.baomoi.com/226/148/14183763.aspx
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:113)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at com.tornado.docbaomoi.db.ArticlesDB.insert(ArticlesDB.java:64)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at com.tornado.docbaomoi.ui.MainFragment$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainFragment.java:114)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at com.tornado.docbaomoi.ui.MainFragment$JSONParse.onPostExecute(MainFragment.java:1)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
06-29 11:03:06.025: E/SQLiteDatabase(19205):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What should I do to solve this ?

Comment: There's a schema constraint violation but you haven't shown your schema. Please post it i.e. the `CREATE TABLE` SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Error inserting content=null

This means you have a column that's set to be not NULL, but you didn't supply a value for it.  You must supply a value for any column that has a not NULL constraint.

Answer (score -1):

To add to what Gabe said,

You can also replace the value with a whitespace in case its null and add this check to all values being inserted :

```
if(value == null) {
    value = " ";
}
```

Comment: Circumventing the constraint does not make sense if the inserted value is not actually valid.

Comment: It actually depends a lot on what his non null columns are and if he really wants them non null. There can be cases where might want to keep fields blank incase the user didn't enter anything.